# Flutter Release APK for playstore

Tags: android, flutter, multi-device-hybrid-apps, release-apk

I am trying to generate a build apk, but getting following error.
this is compatible with flutter version **2.8.1**

**Getting following error while run flutter build apk**

---

```
/home/dell/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color build apk

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

Note: /home/dell/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geocoding-2.0.2/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geocoding/GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/dell/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_maps_flutter-2.1.1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/googlemaps/Convert.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: /home/dell/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/path_provider_android-2.0.11/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/pathprovider/PathProviderPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: /var/projects/app/freshooo/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/u6amtech/flutter_grocery/Application.kt: (11, 51): Unresolved reference: setPluginRegistrant
e: /var/projects/app/freshooo/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/u6amtech/flutter_grocery/FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.kt: (15, 44): Unresolved reference: registerWith
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          126.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

---

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: flutter_grocery
description: A new Flutter application.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

version: 1.1.0+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  provider: ^5.0.0
  http: ^0.13.1
  freezed: ^0.14.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  photo_view: ^0.12.0
  dio: ^4.0.0-prev2
  image_picker: ^0.7.3
  pin_code_fields: ^7.0.0
  google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.3
  flutter_google_places: ^0.3.0
  geocoding: ^2.0.0
  geolocator: ^7.0.1
  shimmer_animation: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.2
  firebase_core: ^1.7.0
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.8
  flutter_local_notifications: ^8.2.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  flutter_html: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.2
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  fluro: ^2.0.3
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  universal_html: ^2.0.8
  universal_ui: ^0.0.8
  flutter_widget_from_html_core: ^0.6.1
  phone_number: ^0.11.0+2
  country_code_picker: ^2.0.2
  flutter_typeahead: ^3.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/image/
    - assets/language/

  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/font/Poppins-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.fresh.grocery"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << '-Xlint:-options'
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

**key.properties**

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=~/home/dell/upload-keystore.jks
```

**Project Setting**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please don't show confidential code like your package name, key.properties file kindly edit and remove those to protect your app from malicious itentions.

Since your `flutter` version is 2.8.1 but your dart sdk in `pubspec.yaml` is `sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"` it requires to enable null-safety for your project just change the `2.7.0` to `2.12.0` or above, and also do require changes for flutter null safety for more details check out this https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

You maybe getting this error as some of the packages you used in your project use null-safety so migrate your app to null-safety.

You can check this for more details about generating production apps https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

you can also use this code to generate a obfuscated apk

```
flutter build apk --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info={directory}
```

similarly for appbundle:

```
flutter build appbundle --release --obfuscate --split-debug-info={directory}
```

Answer (score 0):

For release playstore build change

this in `app/build.gradle`

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

to

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did the same but no changes in the error

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your `Application` class in the `Manifest` file?

like this :

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:label="Fresh">

Comment: When I run `flutter run --release`. It's run on chrome successfully without any error.